# Can I setup and enforce additional WiFi connection (and password) requirements on managed laptops using Windows or MacOS?

Tags: network, windows, wifi, client, network-access-control

Can I setup and enforce additional WiFi connection (and password) requirements on managed laptops using Windows or MacOS?

Such as:

- blocking (or entirely hiding) the option to connect to open networks
- blocking (or entirely hiding) networks that use weak protocols such as WEP or WPA
- only allowing connection to WPA2/WPA3 networks if the password meets certain requirements such as minimum length, certain characters or strength, no simple passwords with repeated characters, not on password block lists?
- using allow or deny lists for access point mac addresses?
- using allow or deny lists of ssid names?

Comment: "what are other common restrictions that can be applied" is a little too open-ended. What problem do you want to solve?

Comment: Removed that part. Preventing users from connecting to 'very' insecure networks and/or warn them if they do or did. On semi-managed employee devices, ideally only allow connecting to their home and office WiFi networks if some requirements are met.

Comment: "Managed" how? Active Directory and GPOs? I'm thinking this is more of a ServerFault question because it will likely end up as a configuration question. The answer to "can you?" is 'yes'. But then you'll want to know "how?"

Comment: For example: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2088556-can-we-use-gpo-to-block-users-from-connecting-to-any-wireless-network I googled for "gpo [insert your bullet point]"

Comment: So group policies are the only, and the best option for Windows? How about for MacOS? My question is broader than that, as the bullet points try to reflect. Also, how should this be managed (enrolled, enforced, monitored) cross-devices in a scalable way?

Comment: GPO is the most common way, is applicable for Windows and Mac, and hits most of your points. If nothing else, that's where you'd start. So, you're moving towards where I thought you'd go, which is drifting this out-of-scope.

Comment: The problem is that the answer is 'yes', but the 'how' is tricky. GPOs, endpoint agents, 3rd party authentication systems can combine to accomplish what you want. But, ultimately, the answer is "yes".

Comment: Lovely how the community always keeps me sharp with unvarnished constructive feedback.